# Sorting an array of objects by value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort an array of objects, which is huge.

I have created the following functions. I have a compare function that looks like this:

```
  WordCounter.prototype.compare = function(a, b) {
    if (Object.values(a) < Object.values(b)) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (Object.values(a) > Object.values(b)) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  };
```

I then reference it in this function:

```
WordCounter.prototype.sortArray = function(array) {

    this.sortedArray = array.sort(this.compare);
  };
```

I then iterate over the array using the below function, it does sort the objects a bit but it seems to do it in chunks:

```
  WordCounter.prototype.returnWords = function(array) {
    for (var key in array) {
      return array[key];
    }
  };
```

Here is some dummy data for reference, there are actually thousands of objects in the array though:

```
[{tongues: 1}, {unpleasant: 50}, {sneak: 13}, {marched: 12}, {flaming: 2}]
```

I need to sort it like this:

```
[{unpleasant: 50}, {sneak: 13}, {marched: 12}, {flaming: 2}, {tongues: 1}]
```

Any idea why it is only sorting a little bit and not the whole array of hashes?

Comment: returning inside a for loop is a bad idea: it will stop the for loop immediately. Please provide some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: oh yes, thanks! - changed it to console.log for now

Comment: Also `Object.values(a) < Object.values(b)` looks suspicious: `values` returns an array ... What do you expect the comparison to do with arrays?

Comment: Hmm I see, I'm trying to sort the array by the values in each function. Do you know how I can access these when the keys are all differently named?

Comment: @Freddy based on which object property do you want to sort the array? Can you provide a sample of a couple of objects in your array?

Comment: Provide some sample data in your question, and what you expect as result.

Comment: Yep - dummy array below
`[{waitingwaiting: 1}, {struggle: 1}, {parr: 5}]`

Comment: ... and the desired output?

Comment: I've updated the question now, thank you!

Comment: Your objects are guaranteed to have exactly one property?

Comment: Yep, all one word and a single number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a helper function `getValue` to get a value from an object, assuming it has just one property, and sort by that:

```js
function getValue(obj) {
    for (let key in obj) return obj[key]; // return any value found in the object
}

// Sample data
var arr = [{tongues: 1}, {unpleasant: 50}, {sneak: 13}, {marched: 12}, {flaming: 2}];

// Sort it
arr.sort((a, b)  => getValue(b) - getValue(a));

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Concise & clever

Comment: @trincot, do you know, which of the access of the first key is faster, `Object.keys`, `for in` or an iterator?

Comment: In this particular case it does not matter much, since the object is expected to have only one enumerable, own property (and no inherited ones), but if an object would have a multitude of enumerable, own properties, `for..in` (or any other way to consume the iterator) will be much faster. `Object.keys` will have to retrieve all properties, while only one is needed.